# Encryption 256 bytes block size, which algorithm can do that?

Tags: .net, encryption

I was looking to AES, but as I understood blocks have to be 16bytes, it's not what I need. I wonder if that any algorithm that can encrypt blocks with 256 bytes length, and it should be on a .net library of cause. Maybe 3DES? or RSA?

Comment: Why do you need to have a specific block size in the encryption?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen because I'm sending data from .net to the MCU through USB within 256 bytes, and I want to make it encrypted, therefore if I will use aes128 ill need to split my 256 bytes then decrypt it, only then write in MCU's flash, its not speed efficient

Comment: I don’t understand why you’d need to split anything or how it would be inefficient. The encryption libraries accept any amount of data usually and handle things themselves. There’s much more difference in the speed of the algorithm than whatever effect the block size has

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen if we are talking about AES128, according to the Wikipedia, it takes 16bytes plaintext, encrypt it with the 16bytes key then output 16bytes Ciphertext. THerefore i can't put 256bytes to this, i have to split it by 16bytes first. Yes, .net library will do everything for you all you need is to show it plaintext. But mcu libraries can't do that, because it's in c. it asks for 16bytes Ciphertext and key for it

Comment: I don't understand why that is an issue.  Encrypt two different blocks with the same key and send them in order.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being in c. Loop 16 times and you have 256 bytes. That’s it. Not a problem and not a performance issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wonder if that any algorithm that can encrypt blocks with 256 bytes length, and it should be on a .net library of cause. Maybe 3DES? or RSA?

Most of the ciphers are having reasonably short block size. To encrypt any longer plaintext you can use different [mode of operations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) giving you option to encrypt longer input and reuse the same key

Most of the crypto libraries implement different modes for you, however it's not so difficult to do it yourself.

if you are looking for something much more simple (and faster) to encrypt input of arbitritrary length, you can use as well some sort of stream cipher(e. g. one time pad with [Salsa20](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20)).